# Count Rows with Text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to count the number of rows with text but not count the number of text. For example, in the table below there are six rows with text. If I used a Counta then it would return 11 but I want it to return the number of rows with text. In my scenario I need it to return 6. There is no specific criteria other than you're only counting each row once that has text and not counting each the number of pieces of text. Is there a way to do this?

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One |  | Three |
| One |  |  |
|  | Two | Three |
| One |  | Three |
|  | Two | Three |
| One | Two |  |

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
=SUM(--(MMULT(--(A2:C7<>""),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A2:C7)^0))>0))
```

This is an array formula and depending on ones version may require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

If one has LET and SEQUENCE we can use LET and have only one reference to change:

```
=LET(rng,A2:C7,SUM(--(MMULT(--(rng<>""),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(rng),,1,0))>0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a helper column, containing the concatenation of the three columns, and apply the `CountA()` worksheet function on that?

You can easily concatenate using the formula `=A1&B1&C1`, for every row.

Comment: That will not work.  COUNTA considers an empty string returned by a formula as TRUE and counts it.

Comment: But you can use: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(D2:D7<>""))` instead of COUNTA with the helper column

Comment: ... and what about `COUNTIF()`, combined with `"NOT(ISBLANK())"` in the criteria section?

Comment: No, ISBLANK will also see it as having data.

Comment: ... and `"<>"""`? (How many double quotes?)

Comment: You cannot use COUNTIF for this for the same reason.  The only way is SUMPRODUCT.